# Problemas Xamarin método Assincrono

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, assincronismo, xamarin-studio

No evento de um botão da minha APP tinha o seguinte código ele funcionava rodando no emulador do android, mas quando passei o app para o celular gera um mensagem o app parou.

```
        Button buttonPessoasNecessita = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.mybuttonPesNec);
        buttonPessoasNecessita.Click += delegate {
        Service1Client client;
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding () { Name= "basicHttpBinding", MaxReceivedMessageSize = 67108864,};

        binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas() 
        { MaxArrayLength = 2147483646, MaxStringContentLength = 5242880, }; 

        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0,60,60); 
        binding.SendTimeout= timeout; 
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout; 
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout; 


        client = new Service1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress ("http://engb.uni5.net/Service1.svc")); 

        buttonPessoasNecessita.text = client.envioPessoa();

        };
```

Tentando solucionar o caso pensei em utilizar de forma assíncrona, procurei vários exemplos mas nenhum ficou claro pra mim e vi que meu objeto 'client' existe um método tem um método beginenvioPessoa() e outro endenvioPessoa();
Baseado nesse link [Easy way to use WCF service with async/await](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35546/easy-way-to-use-wcf-service-with-async-await) tentei montar um método para consumir o web service de forma async

chamada do metodo:

```
      var t = await executeAsync(binding);
```

Metodo:

```
       public async Task<string> executeAsync(BasicHttpBinding binding){

        Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, new EndpointAddress ("http://engb.uni5.net/Service1.svc")); 

        var t = Task<string>.Factory.FromAsync (
            ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).BeginenvioPessoa,
            ((IService1)client.InnerChannel).EndenvioPessoa);
        return await t;
    }
```

No final meu código não funciona exibe erros de sintaxe

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync(System.IAsyncResult,
>   System.Func)' has some invalid arguments
>   (CS1502)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'System.IAsyncResult' (CS1503)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No segundo tu deve procurar um `envioPessoa` que retorna uma `Task<T>` e fazer `await` antes de chamar. Mas o teu primeiro exemplo deve ser mais simples. No primeiro código qual  o erro que dava?

Answer (score 2):

Como você está precisando usar a forma assíncrona provavelmente o que precisa é isto:

```
    using (var client = new Service1Client())
    {
        string resultado = await client.envioPessoaAsync();
    }
```

Imaginando que criou o `ServiceReference`com os métodos  *Task based*. Caso contrário estará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se criou com o padrão que coloca `async` no nome fica um pouco maior:

```
    using (var client = new Service1Client())
    {
        client.envioPessoaCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            //Vai executar esse trecho só quando retornar
            string resultado = e.Result;
        };
        //Vai efetivamente fazer a chamada e quando
        // o resultado  retornar cairá no trecho acima
        client.envioPessoaAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Então Canova problema é que esses métodos com final async e Completed não foram gerados, mesmo eu tendo habilitado pra gerar o Async.

Comment: @DiegoFilipePedroSantos Tá , tu marcou o checkbox e depois selecionou o "Generate asynchronous operations" no radio button? Porque é isso que deveria gerar o método com Async no nome.

Comment: Entendi fiz isso sim, mas não gerou esses metodos, será que por versão do framework ou  porque estou usando Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @DiegoFilipePedroSantos Provavelmente por causa do Xamarin Studio. Quando o tipo do retorno do método `envioPessoa`? QUe opções tu tem no drop de `Generate Asynchronous`?

Comment: Só BeginenvioPessoa EndenvioPessoa

Comment: @DiegoFilipePedroSantos QUe opções tu tem no drop de `Generate Asynchronous`?

Comment: Generate Asynchronous: Assync ou No.

Comment: Generate Asynchronous: Assync ou No. @VitorCanova

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32671/discussion-between-vitor-canova-and-diego-filipe-pedro-santos).